# Fstab - Try rw first, then fall back to ro

Tags: mount, fstab

How can I make an fstab entry to try to first mount as *read-write*, and if it that fails, as *read-only*?

Comment: If I try to mount a read-only block device, the `mount` command automatically falls back to mounting the file system read-only. This is the message printed by `mount` when I do so: `mount: block device /dev/loop2 is write-protected, mounting read-only`

Answer (score 6):

You have to set options to `errors=remount-ro` your entry will look like:

```
<device>  <mount point> <fs type> errors=remount-ro <dump> <pass>
```

Comment: This does not sound exactly what was being asked for. `remount-ro` is used to turn a file system previously mounted read-write into one mounted (more or less) read-only in case any file system corruption is detected. The question to me sounds like it is asking for the file system to be mounted read-only if mounting read-write is not possible in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, this wasn't what I was asking after all.